# Missing Paste (P) option in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, copy-paste, cut-and-paste

I'm copying some data from a webpage which is tabulated. When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Excel 2010 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, it pastes correctly.

However, in Excel 2016, the Paste (P) option is not there.

Only - Keep Source Formatting (K) - Match Destination Formatting (M).

I have repaired office, disabled add-ins in Excel safe mode, removed Skype to Call on browser, tried modifying registry keys.

None of these work. It works fine on Excel 2010. I just want to see the Paste (P) option but can't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Adding some images — 1st one shows no Paste(P) option but second one does. Why isn't the Paste(P) option always available???

[image][image]

Comment: You may want to try copying it a few times in a row. Sometimes it doesn't copy it correctly

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add a couple of screenshots showing what happens in Excel 2010 and in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Advanced Options panel (`Office Button` → `Excel Options` → `Advanced`), scroll down to the `Cut, copy and paste` section and make sure the `Show Paste Options buttons` checkbox is ticked:

[image: Screenshot of Options Pane]

After copying, do a Paste Special as Text (`Home` → `Clipboard` → `Paste` → `Paste Special…` → `Text` → `OK`):

[image: Screenshot of Paste Special dialog box]

Finally, click the Paste Options button and select `Use Text Import Wizard`:

[image: Screenshot showing selecting the Text Import Wizard]

Comment: Thanks, however when I do this, I am still only presented with two paste options still - Keep Source Formatting and Match Destination Formatting.

Comment: @RShome Even after doing a Paste Special As Text? That's weird! Does `Data` > `Data Tools` > `Text to Columns` work?

Comment: @RShome Ah! In Excel 365 2016, the Text Import Wizard has been disabled. It can be re-enabled via `File` > `Options` > `Data` > `Show legacy data import wizards` and ticking the `From Text (Legacy)` checkbox. Not sure if that's applicable as I don't have Excel 2016..

Comment: Thanks @robinCTS. I can't see those options but I think it's because I am on a client site and everything is very locked down for Excel.

Comment: @RShome Well, the legacy data import options should only be available for Office *365*. The `Text to Columns` tool *should* be available even in a locked down Excel. It's not an option. You access it from the `Data` tab in the `Data Tools` section. Since you're on a client computer, maybe you can take a couple of photos of the screen and upload them so it's clear what the issue is?

Comment: Hi @robinCTS when I copy text, only the Paste as Text option is available. I want the Paste(P) option to be available as well. It appears I can't add images here

Comment: @RShome That's right. You can only post *links* to images you upload somewhere else. However, you did the best thing by adding them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above solutions are not working then just do below;

Whenever you copy text/table etc. from any source just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> two times frequently and go to wherever you want to paste, and right-click there, you will get the special paste option.